Notation based on $\langle.\,,u\rangle$ for defining bounded linear functional
I found the following sentence:
"the objective is to give a bounded linear functional $T = \langle.\,,u\rangle \in C[0,1]^*$"
I know already that $C[0,1]^*$ is the dual spaces to the continuous functions on the interval $[0,1]$, however, I have no clue, what the $\langle.\,,u\rangle$ shall tell me, and Google does not help much. So does anyone know the term to look for or have a quick explanation?
thanks

Use \langle and \rangle for delimiters, rather than < and >.

@Arturo: thank you :)

$\langle\cdot,u\rangle$ stands for the mapping $f\mapsto\langle f,u\rangle$.
Without any further information, I'd assume
$$\langle f,u\rangle=\int_0^1f(t)u(t)dt.$$

@whpowell96 I don't understand your second sentence. What does differentiability ("$C^1$") have to do with it, and why does the map's boundedness contradict the existence of an inner product?

I misread $C$ as $C^1$ and misspoke. My comment was more for OP just to say that the notation is used most often used for inner products and here is extended to a broader setting. Boundedness of the map does not contradict the existence of a complete inner product space but it happens to be the case here that $u$ can be discontinuous and $T$ remains bounded so it has been extended beyond the original domain of definition of an inner product.

@stefan: Thank you very much! Never would have found that out! Great!! :-)
